# Transport calculations with AMSET package

Tags: electronic-transport

I am trying to calculate transport properties using the AMSET package (with VASP), to be able to calculate the electron relaxation time.

My system is a monolayer of graphene doped with isoelectronic doping units. I understand that the treatment of doping atoms in regard to electron-impurity scattering could be problematic.

Does someone have experience and/or comments on the usage of the supercell approach in the modelling of periodically doped materials with AMSET?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been more than 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find an answer. However, due to the lack of documentation and support, I am not using AMSET anymore.